# How do I get two tables to align in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm having trouble aligning these two tables together in LateX. The bottom one keeps getting skewed to the right. Is there a workaround for this?

```
\usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{5cm}|  }
         \hline
         \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Multi-class Classifiers for $n=5$} \\
         \hline
        Classifier & Accuracy \\
         \hline
         Linear SVM   & 50.9 \\
         Gaussian SVM &   51.4 \\
         Linear (one-vs-all) SVM & 47.2 \\
         Gaussian (one-vs-all) SVM    & 50.5 \\
         Adaboost & 52.3 \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{5cm}|  }
         \hline
         \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Multi-class classifiers for $n=7$} \\
         \hline
        Classifier & Accuracy \\
         \hline
         Linear SVM   & 53.0 \\
         Gaussian SVM &   51.0 \\
         Linear (one-vs-all) SVM & 50.0 \\
         Gaussian (one-vs-all) SVM    & 49.5 \\
         Adaboost & 51.5 \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
```

Comment: You should consider asking this on the Tex/LaTex SE site instead.

Comment: your example works perfectly fine for me! nothing is skewed. can you elaborate on how you would want it to be aligned?